# TwinColSelect + Vaadin + Java + Add a new Listener

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to add a listener to buttons of TwinColSelect of Vaadin.
I want to show a form and get information from user before sending the selected item to right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the TwinColSelect component.

It would be relatively simple to simulate your own TwinColSelect component as a server-side component with two `ListSelect` components and the appropriate buttons, and implementing your own button handling logic.